# Load preferences.xml without extending PreferenceActivity

Tags: android

Can I load preferences.xml without extending PreferenceActivity? I need this because:

1. I want custom title bar
2. I want all of my Activities to extend my AbstractActivity

Comment: How did you implement this? Did you use PreferenceManager?

Comment: I used PreferenceActivity. It's possible to set custom title bar (try to search here, there's an answer describing how to do this).

Comment: what about your second statement: "I want all of my Activities to extend my AbstractActivity" ? Did you implement it somehow?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that its very easy, and can't test it right now, but technically it should be possible...

You should use [PreferenceManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html) that has a `createPreferenceScreen(Context ctx)` method that (obviously) returns a [PreferenceScreen](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceScreen.html), which, according to docs:

> Represents a top-level Preference that is the root of a Preference hierarchy. A PreferenceActivity points to an instance of this class to show the preferences.

And this class in turn has a `getView(View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method that returns a `View`, and according to docs:

> Gets the View that will be shown in the PreferenceActivity.

So I suppose that setting this returned View in your activity should display the same as the `PreferenceActivity`...

Answer (score 2):

You can re-implement `PreferenceActivity` in your own activity class. Here's the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.java) of `PreferenceActivity` class.

It's rather small, so I don't think it'll be difficult to understand it.